# How to move an image for universal app on ipad only

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created an app which got rejected from the app store due to a slight bug in the interface of the ipad version. The interface looks fine on the iphone version its just the ipad version that has the bug. What i would need to do is move the score up a few pixels (only on the ipad version), how would i go about doing this. Below is an image of the bug, and the associated code. Thanks

```
    m_spBox = newSprite(@"boxes", G_SWIDTH/2, getY(2000), self, 0, RATIO_XY);
CCLabelTTF *lbScore = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", g_nScore] fontName:@"8BIT WONDER" fontSize:30/g_fScaleR];
lbScore.position = ccp(250*G_SCALEX/g_fScaleR, 200*G_SCALEY/g_fScaleR);
lbScore.color = ccGREEN;
[m_spBox addChild:lbScore];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, just in one trouble area, you can check the idiom of the user's device.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() ==         UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
// iPad-specific interface here
}
else
{
// iPhone and iPod touch interface here
}
```

Comment: I tried that, and for some reason when I change the ipad specific interface it doesnt respond. When I try to move the score up a few pixels, and run it on the simulator it doesnt seem to work.